# Cannot get the data in the controller from the service

Tags: angularjs

```html
app.service('customersService', function ($http) {
    this.getCustomer = function (id) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/getCustomer',
            params: {id: id},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
    };
});
```

Cannot get the data in the controller from the service 
The problem with this code is when i try to run this

```
customersService.getCustomer(customerID).then
```

It generates an error mentioned below:

> angular.js:13294 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

The main thing is the call to the service is generated and if i try to print the results on the console in the service the data is there. However i cannot get the data in my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error becuase you are not returning the promise from `$http` GET request.

Edit your code like this:

```js
app.service('customersService', function ($http) {
    this.getCustomer = function (id) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/getCustomer',
            params: {id: id},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        });
    };
});
```

And then with `.then()` in your controller, you handle the response data.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, customerService){

    customersService.getCustomer(customerID)
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.data = response;
      })
})
```

Comment: Works pretty much fine now. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You simply forget to return the $http promise that is why `undefined` is returned. You need to do the following:

```
...
return $http({ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try given code.

```
app.service('customersService', function ($http) {
  var getCustomer = function (id) {
      return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/getCustomer',
            params: {id: id},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        })
  };

    var customersService = {
            getCustomer: getCustomer
    }
    return ProfileService;

});
```